# How to setup Sentry in .NET Azure functions

Tags: .net, azure-functions, sentry

Sentry documentation only mentions the AspNetCore version

https://sentry.io/getcodepl/aspnet-core/getting-started/dotnet-aspnetcore/

Comment: Sentry does not currently have direct guidance for Azure Functions.  It is in our backlog, and you can track the issue here - which has some notes.  Thanks.
https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/373#issuecomment-1434966908

Answer (score 2):

1. Install package
   `Install-Package Sentry.AspNetCore`
2. Setup handling in azure function

```
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public static async Task RunAsync([TimerTrigger("0 */5 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo myTimer, ILogger log)
        {
            using (SentrySdk.Init())
            {
                try
                {
                   //Code
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    SentrySdk.CaptureException(ex);
                    throw;  //if you want to pass it into Azure
                }
            }
        }
```

3. Configure DSN in `local.settings.json`

```json
  "Values": {
    "SENTRY_DSN": "https://your-dsn-url.ingest.sentry.io/xxx"
  }
```

Comment: If you're just using plain .NET SDK (Sentry nuget package) you don't need to install Sentry.AspNetCore even. Just Sentry. I also suggest using `await SentrySdk.FlushAsync(TimeSpan.FromSecond(2));` after calling capture (before `throw` ) to make sure Sentry gets the event, in case the lambda process is frozen/shut down. Though getting out of `using` should already dispose and flush things out (though blocking the thread since Dispose is sync there)

Comment: Hi.  Please note that the approach of initializing Sentry in each function call is not advised.  Please refer to https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/373#issuecomment-1434966908. Thanks.